# Xcode 6.3.1 Autocomplete bug or Parse sdk 1.7.1 bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

After updating Xcode to version 6.3.1 and Parse SDK to 1.7.1 the Xcode Autocompletion feature won't work properly.

Xcode autocompletes my code with:

```
[queryPhotoCount countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFIntegerResultBlock(nullable )block ...
```

Instead of:

```
[queryPhotoCount countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
```

Is it a bug of Xcode or a bug of the SDK of Parse?

Comment: Autocomplete doesn't work on #imports for me either on v6.3.1.

Comment: i got it fixed, with a little change on the headers on parse, this is just temporary hacked, to make blocks work, i reset these changes once i uploaded a new build. verified this on parse 1.7.4 and xcode 6.3.2

in PFConstants.h, remove all instance of "PF_NULLABLE_S" and in PFQuery.h, remove all instance of "PF_NULLABLE", "PF_NULLABLE_S", "PF_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN" and "PF_ASSUME_NONNULL_END"

you will get warning "Nullability Issue" but on my testing works great, also i reset this headers back when I upload a new build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typedef'd blocks are now correctly expanded by Xcode with the right names and types, which wasn't the case in its older versions.

Though there is some unexpected behavior with the recently introduced `nullable` annotation, which was also introduced in the latest versions of the Parse SDK.

Here is a snippet with the correct and incorrect cases:

```
typedef void (^BDCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSError *error);

- (void)foo:(int)bar {
    // This will expand automatically and compiles just fine
    [self methodA:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        // Completion goes here
    }];

    // This line expands automatically and does NOT compile at all
    self methodB:(nullable BDCompletionHandler(nullable )completion;

    // This line was typed manually and DOES compile correctly
    [self methodB:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        // Completion goes here
    }];
}

- (void)methodA:(BDCompletionHandler)completion {
    // Do some stuff
}

- (void)methodB:(nullable BDCompletionHandler)completion {
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

So, I guess the answer is **Yes**, it is a bug in Xcode.

Comment: I updated Parse sdk to 1.7.2 and the problem persists .. is frustrating!

Comment: @RajaRao the snippet just explains that there is a bug in that specific version of Xcode, it has nothing to do with the SDK and the update process.